# Typescript cannot find name window or document

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

For either case:

```
document.getElementById('body');
// or
window.document.getElementById('body');
```

I get `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'window'.`

Am I missing something in `tsconfig.json` for a definition file I should install?

I get the message when running `tsc` and in `vscode`

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "target": "ES2016",
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types/",
            "typings/index.d.ts"
        ]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*-aot.ts"
    ]
}
```

My Answer:
For use with `tsconfig.json` I target `es5` and use `lib: ["es2015", "dom"]`

Comment: Where do you get that error? In your IDE, or when running `tsc`? What is your current `tsconfig.json` file? You need to provide more relevant information if you want help

Comment: @NitzanTomer I added the information you requested.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

It seems that the problem is caused by targeting `ES2016`.
Are you targeting that for a reason? If you target `es6` the error will probably go away.

Another option is to specify the libraries for the compiler to use:

```
tsc -t ES2016 --lib "ES2016","DOM" ./your_file.ts
```

Which should also make the error go away.

I'm not sure why the libs aren't used by default, in the [docs for compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) it states for the `--lib` option:

> Note: If --lib is not specified a default library is injected. The
>   default library injected is:
>   ► For --target ES5: DOM,ES5,ScriptHost
>   ► For --target ES6: DOM,ES6,DOM.Iterable,ScriptHost

But it doesn't state what are the default libraries when targeting `ES2016`.
It might be a bug, try to open an issue, if you do please share the link here.

Comment: Targeting ES6 did the trick! I originally targeted ES2016 because I plan to put the resulting javascript through webpack so I didn't think it would make much difference.

Comment: It makes sense to me that `--lib`s would have to be explicitly declared instead of some arbitrary defaults.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue at code time in VSCode with an Angular 2 project built with Angular CLI, and switching to "es6" in both/either tsconfig.json and tsconfig.app.json didn't resolve it; neither did adding "dom" to tsconfig.json (it's already in tsconfig.app.json). There are no compile-time or runtime errors, but the red squiggly is annoying while coding.

Comment: @S.Greylyn If there are no compile errors then it's an issue with your VSCode. I've never used it.

Comment: @S.Greylyn use `"lib": ["dom"]` in `tsconfig.json`. That worked for me.

Comment: Baffled what target actually does, is it just for typedefs? And lib... is also for typedefs?

Comment: @DominicTobias `target` specifies to which version of js the output of the compilation. For example, if you want your code to run on older browsers, you don't want `es6` feature (and above). The `lib` option has default values based on the `target`. You can override the defaults if you're sure that the environment at runtime does include the features.

Comment: Also of note: If you already have `lib` in your `tsconfig.json`, it might help to remove it again. `lib` will be autofilled with what makes sense for your `target` but if you have already defined `lib`, it will be left as-is, meaning you might miss some libs.

Comment: @S.G. I have now the same issue after accidentely ctrl-clicked on `window` in code at VSCode Editor. I also have `dom` in tscofig `lib` setting. Did you solved the issue?

Comment: @kolyaseg I believe I either found some VSCode setting that disabled linting for that particular error, or I just ignored it until that project was done, but I cannot rightly remember. Good luck.

Answer (score 165):

use

```
"lib": ["dom"]
```

in tsconfig.json

e.g.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es5", "es6", "dom"],
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*"]
}
```

Comment: FWIW this is what solved it for me. Should be the accepted answer, because in some situations (starter kits or tools that already take care of running `tsc` for you, you're not so easily able to change the CLI args passed to it, but you almost surely control `tsconfig.json`)

Comment: i have added this to my lib but its not still working.    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "es6",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],

Comment: Same @AdharshM...I wonder is there a recent issue?

Comment: I'm also encountering an issue, my code was working fine and then it wasn't, but I hadn't changed anything TS-related and was already using `dom`. I'll try use an older version of TS, I updated yesterday (but didn't notice this issue since)

Comment: @AdharshM  This is likely due to https://github.com/lquixada/cross-fetch/issues/104, at least that was the case for me.

Answer (score 29):

If you are using `bun` instead of `node`, then you need to use `bun add @types/web -D`.

The problem is explained at https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/issues/3030

#### Solution

https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/issues/463#issuecomment-1636727109

Note: Adding the types reference to your `tsconfig.json`, as explaining on the GitHub issue, looks not to be mandatory. Only installing the dependency looks enough to get rid of the error.

Comment: Thanks. This is the solution for `bun` for the moment.

Comment: Same here. i added to one of the monorepo packages the bun and it broke the types for all of the other packages. doing this resolve it.

Answer (score 13):

**Update**: To avoid having to add these references to every file, see [stackoverflow.com/a/77103144](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77103144/5936629)

I was using bun, and adding the following triple-slash directives at the top of the relevant TypeScript file solved it:

```
/// <reference lib="dom" />
/// <reference lib="dom.iterable" />
```

This is because setting `"types": ["bun-types"]` means TypeScript will ignore other global type definitions, including `lib: ["dom"]`.

The same applies to other global type definition libs like webworker.

See [how to add DOM types in bun's documentation](https://bun.sh/docs/typescript#dom-types) for up-to-date information.

Comment: Bun's documentation mentions [how to add DOM types](https://bun.sh/docs/runtime/typescript#add-dom-types) without removing `bun-types` from your `tsconfig.json` types.

Comment: @NielThiart Thanks, i updated the answer to reflect the docs. Even though I haven't tested the solution, this fix sounds like it is a lot better.

Answer (score 5):

For me, running this command fixed my issue.

```
npm add -d @types/web
```

Comment: same for me. Already had lib: ["dom"] was missing "types": ["web"]

Answer (score 1):

What fixed it for me was changing `tsconfig.json`'s `"target"` to `"es6"`. It was `"es2015"` before.