# Error in IE 11 browser - EXCEPTION: Object doesn't support property or method 'matches' , other browser it works fine

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, internet-explorer

In my case, the webpage works fine in firefox and chrome browser but in IE v.11 it shows error as  [error comes in IE 11 DEVELOPER TOOLS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hri5N.png).  The error shows up in developer tools of the IE 11. The error does not allow to open a perticular link , on clicking it shows the following error.

[image: In all browser it runs fine but in IE 11 the following error pops up. any help.]

polyfills.ts -

```
* BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following to support `@angular/animation`. */
 import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.


/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';


/** ALL Firefox browsers require the following to support `@angular/animation`. **/
// import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.



/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.



/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */

/**
 * Date, currency, decimal and percent pipes.
 * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE11 and Safari 10
 */
// import 'intl';  // Run `npm install --save intl`.
```

tsconfig.spec.json -

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2016"
    ],
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "test.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2015"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the fact that window is underlined red is independent of the error you are experiencing.

Comment: Can you post a copy of your typescript config, as well as any polyfills you are using?

Comment: @DerekBrown sure will update in the question description.

Comment: @DerekBrown i was able to get rid of red underline issue by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41336301/typescript-cannot-find-name-window-or-document. so now i dont have any window.onload issue. but still in IE11 i do have that error.

Comment: @DerekBrown - i found some link but dont know where to use it and how to use it for this issue, that is prefix ms matchselector https://github.com/WICG/inert/issues/51

Answer (score 28):

I was facing same issue after I updated my project from Angular 5 to 6. I found a solution with help of Derek Brown's comment. The solution is to add the following in the `polyfill.ts` file:

```
if (!Element.prototype.matches) {
  Element.prototype.matches = Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector;
}
```

Answer (score 19):

For those using Angular 6 and 7 (typescript) you should modify Sanjay Gupta's answer below with:

```
if (!Element.prototype.matches) {
  Element.prototype.matches = (<any>Element.prototype).msMatchesSelector ||
    Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector;
}
```

The casting (well, untyping, really) allows the transpiler to parse the undefined method.

Comment: Additional info: this code snippet (to its credit) seems to be based off of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches.

Answer (score 9):

It looks like IE implements the `matches` function using a non-standard name ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)).  That link includes a polyfill which will define the `matches` function so it can be used on IE.

Comment: So in polyfills.ts where should i add the matches function

Comment: Just below the existing polyfill imports should be fine.

Comment: can you plz let me know the syntax as it shows error here as 'cannot find element'.

Comment: so i have included the polyfill below the other imports - if (!Element.prototype.matches)
    Element.prototype.matches =
        Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector ||
        Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector;  but it coming ful red line underlined and says ' property match does not exist on element'

Comment: @stec1 if you're still reading, I have included an answer below that resolves the issue in typescript (which is what, I imagine you are using, given the error that you're getting)