# router-outlet is appending rather than replacing IE 11

Tags: angular

See this example from https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-routes-1rwrv5

The problem happens on IE 11 : when you click on the link home then the link about, then home then about etc.

the router outlet is appending instead of replacing.

This is caused by BrowserAnimationsModule import, how can I make it work with the BrowserAnimationsModule ?

Comment: Stacktrace on IE shows this error:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46715190/error-in-ie-11-browser-exception-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was already reported here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24769
and here [Error in IE 11 browser - EXCEPTION: Object doesn't support property or method 'matches' , other browser it works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46715190/error-in-ie-11-browser-exception-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-m).

The problem is that `Element.matches` does not exist in IE but is needed by the BrowserAnimationsModule.
In order to fix it you have to add the following polyfill to your polyfill.ts:

```
if (!Element.prototype.matches) {
    Element.prototype.matches = Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector;
}
```