# Allow for certain "unfound" variable names in typescript?

Tags: typescript

The module I'm using is supposed to be called in browser as a good old Window object, therefore not being imported into files as a module. For that reason Typescript's compiler freaks out with the `"Cannot find name [variable]"`. Is there a way I can "whitelist" a name that Typescript can't find but I'm sure it will be used at runtime?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript cannot find name window or document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41336301/typescript-cannot-find-name-window-or-document)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
declare var yourVariableName: YourType;
```

At the top of the file where you use `yourVariableName`.  This indicates to the TypeScript compiler that this global variable will exist at runtime.

Comment: Huh, wasn't expecting a downvote for this.  Any reason?

Comment: Your original answer was "try:" and the line of code. Not really useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare any number of variables and extra properties on the window object so that typescript knows about them, but does not emit any code for them. You can even add a type annotations to describe their runtime behavior of these Javascript objects or you can use `any` if you don't mind going untyped.

```
declare var someGlobalVar: any;
declare var someGlobalTypedVar: { 
    doSomething(): number
};

interface Window {
    someCustomWindowProp: any
}

window.someCustomWindowProp = 10 // works
```

You can declare global variables, you can add to existing interfaces, such as `Window` or `Document` depending on your needs.

Comment: Certainly this question has been asked and answered before?