# What is the meaning of error TS2584 (TS) .... Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to include 'dom'?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2019, document.write

I use VS and write Typescript

I would like simply to type the command "document.write" without having an error code.
what I having now is an error code of this commmand "document". I just don't want to get into something complecated as there can be a simple solution ( I didn't experience this problem on my previous PC and VS).

Error message:
Error   TS2584  (TS) Cannot find name 'document'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to include 'dom'.   C:\web development\studies\typescript\replaceCharsInArray\replaceCharsInArray (tsconfig or jsconfig project)    C:\web development\studies\typescript\replaceCharsInArray\replaceCharsInArray\app.ts    9   Active

```
let arr: string[] = ['black ofram','american walnut'];
function replaceCharsInStringArray(arr: string[], oldChar:string, newChar:string): string[] {
    for (let i = 0; i >= arr.length - 1, i++;) {
        arr[i] = arr[i].replace(newChar, oldChar);
        return arr;
    };
}
arr = replaceCharsInStringArray(arr, ' ', '_');
document.write
```

Comment: I googled the error message and this looks promising: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28858#issuecomment-487756300 - updating the tsconfig.js compilerOptions like they say could fix you issue.

Answer (score 12):

Adding `"DOM"` to list of `lib` in `compilerOptions` property to my `tsconfig.json` worked:

```json
{

  "compilerOptions": {
      lib: ["ES2017", "DOM"]
  }
}
```

[Documentation for lib](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib)

Answer (score 8):

As answered to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41336301/typescript-cannot-find-name-window-or-document) question.
It seems that the problem is caused by targeting ES2016.
Are you targeting that for a reason? If you target es6 the error will probably go away.

Another option is to specify the libraries for the compiler to use:

`tsc -t ES2016 --lib "ES2016","DOM" ./your_file.ts`

Which should also make the error go away.

I'm not sure why the libs aren't used by default, in the docs for compiler options it states for the --lib option:

Note: If --lib is not specified a default library is injected. The default library injected is:
► For --target ES5: DOM,ES5,ScriptHost
► For --target ES6: DOM,ES6,DOM.Iterable,ScriptHost

But it doesn't state what are the default libraries when targeting ES2016.
It might be a bug, try to open an issue, if you do please share the link here.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thank you all for helping me out.

I found another simple solution for my problem. 
I realized that I was creating a wrong solution type for my project.
I added this extension: "Typescript Html application Template" and used it for TS project.